# Merge two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a MySQL table `types`where I store product types. I fetch them all and get this array:

```
 [0]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'cars'
    ['category']=>'vehicle'
    …some other stuf…
 [1]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'fruit'
    ['category']=>'food'
    …some other stuf…
 [2]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'vegetables'
    ['category']=>'food'
    …some other stuf…
…
```

Next, I have a table which contains specific `products`. I could fetch them all and get:

```
 [0]=>
    ['codename']=>'fruit'
    ['name']=>'banana'
    …some other stuf…
 [1]=>
    ['codename']=>'fruit'
    ['name']=>'apple'
    …some other stuf…
 [2]=>
    ['codename']=>'vegetables'
    ['name']=>'cauliflower'
    …some other stuf…
 [3]=>
    ['codename']=>'cars'
    ['name']=>'audi'
    …some other stuf…
 [4]=>
    ['codename']=>'cars'
    ['name']=>'volvo'
    …some other stuf…
…
```

I want to construct one single array that contains all the info, like so:

```
 [0]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'cars'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        ['name'] = 'audi'
        …
    [1]=>
        ['name'] = 'volvo'
        …
    ['category']=>'vehicle'
    …

 [1]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'fruit'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        ['name'] = 'banana'
        …
    [1]=>
        ['name'] = 'apple'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …

 [2]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'vegetables'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        ['name'] = 'cauliflower'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …
…
```

I was thinking about first fetching both arrays. Next, I could push the second array in the first in the appropriate place, but I can't figure out how that would work when using `array_push`. Anyone who can help me? Or is there a more elegant solution to accomplish this?

Comment: You have tables. If you mean tables in a database, you can probably join the two tables in your query and fetch the results into the format you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is grouping an multi dimensional array by a specific column and then merge it.

The grouping can be done with `array_reduce`, by creating a new associative array, that uses the categories as keys.

```
$groupedProducts = array_reduce($products, function($carry, $product){
    if (!array_key_exists($product['codename'], $carry)) {
        $carry[$product['codename']] = [];
    }
    $carry[$product['codename']][] = $product;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

This will create the following data structure:

```
$groupedProducts = [
    'fruit' => [
        [
            'codename' => 'fruit',
            'name' => 'banana',
            ... some other stuff ...
        ],
        [
            'codename' => 'fruit',
            'name' => 'apple',
            ... some other stuff ...
        ]
    ],
    'vegetables' => [
        [
            'codename' => 'vegetables',
            'name' => 'cauliflower',
            ... some other stuff ...
        ]
    ],
    'cars' => [
        [
            'codename' => 'cars',
            'name' => 'audi',
            ... some other stuff ...
        ],
        [
            'codename' => 'cars',
            'name' => 'volvo',
            ... some other stuff ...
        ]
    ],
]
```

As you can see all products are grouped by the codename. If you do not want the codename key in the inner arrays you can `unset` it in the `array_reduce` anonymous function, or use `array_intersect_key` in there to select specific keys you want to keep.

You can reuse the code with little adjustments if you want to group the final array by categories as well.

Next comes the merge. Here you can use `array_map` on the initial array to add the sorts to it:

```
$finalArray = array_map(function($type) use ($groupedProducts) {
    if (array_key_exists($type['unique_codename'], $groupedProducts)) {
       $type['sorts'] = $groupedProducts[$type['unique_codename']];
    }
    return $type;
}, $types);
```

This code will create the final array you wanted to build.

Comment: [Here is a running example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2495e368850cc91b913e3d20ea1a2aa7c5935efb) for the code.

Comment: Great! Special thanks for explaining your code, I learned a lot from it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique that will build a list that preserves all unspecified attributes of types and products, and group by type

```
// Build a list of known types
$typeIndex = [];
foreach ($types AS $id=>$type) {
    $typeIndex[] = $type['unique_codename'];
    $merged[$id] = $type;
}

foreach ($products AS $product) {
    $codeIndex = array_search($product['codename'], $typeIndex);
    if ($codeIndex === FALSE) continue;

    // Create sorts array to hold product if necessary
    if (!isset($merged[$codeIndex]['sorts'])) {
        $merged[$codeIndex]['sorts'] = [];
    }

    // Insert product
    $merged[$codeIndex]['sorts'][] = $product;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Your code definitely helps me trying to figure this out, but it's not perfect yet. I see two problems: 1: the merged array only contains `types` that have `products`, while it should show all `types`, even if those `types` have no `products`. 2: if a `product` has a codename that isn't in the `types` list, it's assigned to the first `type`, even though it's not of that `type`.

Comment: How would you like products with unknown types stored? In an 'unknown' type category?

Comment: No, they should be ignore and not show up in the merged array.

Comment: and what about types with no products? empty sorts array?

Comment: Types with no product should show up. I basically want an array containing all the types, and if they have products, all to products assigned to the types. Products that have a type that's not in the types table shouldn't be in the final array.