# Add multi-dimensional array to subarray of other multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Thanks to [Philipp Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948038/merge-two-multi-dimensional-arrays), I was able to merge two multi-dimensional arrays, giving me this final array:

```
[0]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'cars'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘cars’
        ['name'] = 'audi'
        …
    [1]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘cars’
        ['name'] = 'volvo'
        …
    ['category']=>'vehicle'
    …

 [1]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'fruit'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘fruit’
        ['name'] = 'banana'
        …
    [1]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘fruit’
        ['name'] = 'apple'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …

 [2]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'vegetables'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘vegetables’
        ['name'] = 'cauliflower'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …
…
```

Now, I want to merge this array with it too:

```
[0]=>
    ['codename']=>'fruit'
    ['name']=>'banana'
    [‘type’]=>’yellowbanana’
    …some other stuf…
 [1]=>
    ['codename']=>'fruit'
    ['name']=>'banana'
    [‘type’]=>’brownbanana’
    …some other stuf…
 [2]=>
    ['codename']=>’cars’
    ['name']=>’audi’
    [‘type’]=>’a2’
    …some other stuf…
 [3]=>
    ['codename']=>'fruit'
    ['name']=>'banana'
    [‘type’]=>’greenbanana’
    …some other stuf…
 [4]=>
    ['codename']=>’cars’
    ['name']=>’audi’
    [‘type’]=>’a6’
    …some other stuf…
 [5]=>
    ['codename']=>’cars’
    ['name']=>’other’
    [‘type’]=>’dummytext1’
    …some other stuf…
 [6]=>
    ['codename']=>’cars’
    ['name']=>’other’
    [‘type’]=>’dummytext2’
    …some other stuf…
…
```

Which should result in the final (bis) array:

```
[0]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'cars'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘cars’
        ['name'] = 'audi'
        [‘types’]=>
        [0]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘a2’
            …
        [1]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘a6’
            …
     …
    [1]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘cars’
        ['name'] = 'volvo'
        …
    [2]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘cars’
        ['name'] = ‘other’
        [‘types’]=>
        [0]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘dummytext1’
            …
        [1]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘dummytext2’
            …
     …
    ['category']=>'vehicle'
    …

 [1]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'fruit'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘fruit’
        ['name'] = 'banana'
        [‘types’]=>
        [0]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘yellowbanana’
            …
        [1]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘brownbanana’
            …
        [2]=>
            [‘type’] = ‘greenbanana’
            …
       …
    [1]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘fruit’
        ['name'] = 'apple'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …

 [2]=>
    ['unique_codename']=>'vegetables'
    ['sorts']=>
    [0]=>
        [‘codename’] = ‘vegetables’
        ['name'] = 'cauliflower'
        …
    ['category']=>'food'
    …
 …
```

I've tried the same approach as the first merge, but I can't seem to get it right. Since this probably needs a different approach, I've opened a new question for it. Notice that sometimes, a new 'name' should be added to the initial subarray if it wasn't already present ('other' in my example).

Anyone who can help me with this? I'm not an Array Wizard myself, obviously... Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_combine()` to start to use `unique_codename` as keys in the initial array to allow to search on it. Then, you could use a loop, over the new array, and check if the `codename` exists in the "main array". If you could add the new `type` inside the `types` in the main array:

```
$init = array(); // your initial array
$array = array(); // your new array

$init = array_combine(array_column($init, 'unique_codename'), $init);
foreach ($array as $k => $item) {
    if (isset($init[$item['codename']])) {
        foreach ($init[$item['codename']]['sorts'] as &$sort) { // $sort is used as reference
            if ($sort['name'] == $item['name']) {
                $sort['types'][] = $item['type'];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r(array_values($init));
```

Output (See [**online demo**](https://3v4l.org/aOARt)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [unique_codename] => cars
            [sorts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [codename] => cars
                            [name] => audi
                            [types] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => a2
                                    [1] => a6
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [codename] => cars
                            [name] => volvo
                        )

                )

            [category] => vehicle
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [unique_codename] => fruit
            [sorts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [codename] => fruit
                            [name] => banana
                            [types] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => yellowbanana
                                    [1] => brownbanana
                                    [2] => greenbanana
                                )

                        )
```

Example with data:

```
$init = [
    [
        'unique_codename'=>'cars',
        'sorts'=>[
            ['codename' => 'cars', 'name' => 'audi'],
            ['codename' => 'cars', 'name' => 'volvo']
        ],
        'category'=>'vehicle',
    ],
    [
        'unique_codename'=>'fruit',
        'sorts'=>[
            ['codename' => 'fruit', 'name' => 'banana'],
            ['codename' => 'fruit', 'name' => 'apple'],
        ],
        'category'=>'food',
    ],
    [
        'unique_codename'=>'vegetables',
        'sorts'=>[
            ['codename' => 'vegetables', 'name' => 'cauliflower'],
        ],
        'category'=>'food',
    ],
];

$array = [
    ['codename'=>'fruit', 'name'=>'banana', 'type'=>'yellowbanana'],
    ['codename'=>'fruit', 'name'=>'banana', 'type'=>'brownbanana'],
    ['codename'=>'cars', 'name'=>'audi', 'type'=>'a2'],
    ['codename'=>'fruit', 'name'=>'banana', 'type'=>'greenbanana'],
    ['codename'=>'cars', 'name'=>'audi', 'type'=>'a6'],
    ['codename'=>'cars', 'name'=>'other', 'type'=>'dummytext1'],
    ['codename'=>'cars', 'name'=>'other', 'type'=>'dummytext2'],
];

$init = array_combine(array_column($init, 'unique_codename'), $init);
foreach ($array as $k => $item) {
    if (isset($init[$item['codename']])) {
        foreach ($init[$item['codename']]['sorts'] as &$sort) {
            if ($sort['name'] == $item['name']) {
                $sort['types'][] = $item['type'];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r(array_values($init));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This will get me on the right track, for sure. Any chance you could help me to integrate the names that aren't in the initial subarray too (other=>dummytext1 and 2)? Always amazes me how fast you guys can work these things out when it takes me hours to find something like this :s

Comment: You're welcome. You want to create another `"sort"` element like : `['codename' => 'cars', 'name' => 'other','types'=>['dummytext1']]`?

Comment: @binoculars Please, could you check this one ? https://3v4l.org/eJdQr Thank you. I think that's what you need.

Comment: Superb! Thanks again!